# Sturm-Liouville eigenvalues have lower bound

Tags: functional-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, calculus-of-variations, sturm-liouville

I am looking to find a proof that eigenvalues are bounded below for the the general Sturm Liouville equation on an open region $ \Omega \subset \mathfrak R^d $ (perhaps with compact closure),

$Ly -\lambda \rho(\mathbf x) y = -\nabla \cdot \big( p(\mathbf x) \nabla y \big) + q(\mathbf x) y - \lambda \rho(\mathbf x) y = 0, \quad \mathbf x \in \Omega $

where $y $ is twice differentiable, $ p, \rho > 0 $ and boundary conditions on $ \partial\Omega $,

$\alpha(\mathbf s) y + \beta(\mathbf s) \frac{\partial y}{\partial n} = 0 $

($\alpha, \beta$ not both zero).

Can anyone help me find a clear treatment handling of this question?

Comment: For any non-trivial solution $(λ,y)$ you get
$$
\newcommand{\vol}{{\rm vol}}
\newcommand{\area}{{\rm area}}
λ=\frac{
  \int_Ωp(x)\|∇y(x)\|^2\,d\vol(x)
 +\int_Ωq(x)\|y(x)\|^2\,d\vol(x)
 - \int_{∂Ω}y(x)p(x)\langle ∇y(x), n(x)\rangle\,d\area(x)
}{
  \int_Ωρ(x)\|y(x)\|^2\,d\vol(x)
}
$$ so essentially you "only" have to treat the last term in the numerator.

Comment: Thanks so much, and the last term simplified to zero if either of $ \alpha $ or $ \beta $ is zero and if neither is, it becomes

$ \int_{\partial \Omega} p \frac{\beta}{\alpha} \left| \frac{\partial y}{\partial n}\right|^2 ds = \int_{\partial\Omega} p \frac{\alpha}{\beta} \left| y \right|^2 ds $

which is where I get stuck.  I am wondering if it is not true without restrictions on $\alpha, \beta$ - for instance both must have the same sign when non-zero.